# How parse soap result to get <estado> value

Tags: php, parsing, soap, namespaces

I can´t get the  value from soap result  whit some namespaces.

```
$xmlResponse = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$xmlResponse->registerXPathNamespace('s','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$result=$xmlResponse->xpath('//s:Body');
foreach ($result as $body) {   
    
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of `$xmlResponse` and the exact expected output given that sample?